# JSF selectOneMenu not whole List

Tags: list, jsf, selectonemenu

Is it possible to choose only specific items from the list in selectOneMenu? 
For example. I have List Products has many fields like name, id etc. One of it is category (1,2 or 3) I want to have only one category in the selectOneMenu without making new Lists and new classes. Can you help me?

Comment: Can you post a concrete question as your question is pretty unclear?

Comment: Whats the problem of creating list? When not to create one is too much costly!

Comment: You can't only show some items inside a `f:selectItems`. You need to filter your list before.

Comment: `itemDisabled` attribute of `f:selectItems` tag. See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8257987/892994 i hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to set the `value` attribute of `f:selectItems` to a method which filters your original collection.

Otherwise you'd have to implement your own version of `f:selectItems` which allows filtering - as we once did in one of our projects.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work like this:     public List<Product> getProducts() throws SQLException
    {   
        Iterator it = products.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext())
        {
            if(product.getCategory() != 1)
                products.remove(product);
        }
        return products;
    }

Comment: So do you get an error? Nothing at all? What does exactly "doesn't work" mean in this case?

Comment: One more thing - if you return a list of products instead of `SelectItem` objects you have to remember to set `f:selectItems` attributes like `itemValue` and `itemLabel`. If you forgot, that also may cause some problems.